# how to open url in same page, and also can open in newtab using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

it possible? how to do that? for now i just can open in same window

```
<div style='cursor: pointer;' onclick="window.open('dailyreport', '_self');">Daily Report</div>
```

that just for open in same window, if i change like this

```
<div style='cursor: pointer;' onclick="window.open('dailyreport', '_blank');">Daily Report</div>
```

open in newtab.

how to do if i want to open in same window,
also can open in newtab if i want it? thanks

Comment: You want to open at the same time? windows and new tab?

Comment: not same time in one click, but if i click open url in same window, and if i want to open in newtab still able to do it.

Comment: Maybe: $('<a target="_blank" href="/foo/bar.html"></a>').click();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your question with this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function Print_Report() {
        if(confirm("Do you want open on a new tab?") == true) {
            window.open('url.php', '_blank');
        } else {
            window.open('url.php', '_self');
        }
    }
</script>

<div style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='Print_Report();'>Daily Report</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Other possible option is create another div for that:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function Print_Report() {
        window.open('url.php', '_self');
    }

    function Print_ReportNewTab() {
        window.open('url.php', '_blank');
    }
</script>

<div style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='Print_Report();'>Daily Report</div>
<div style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='Print_ReportNewTab();'>Daily Report</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what i want, but it possible to make without confirm? like if left click open same window and right click open new tab?

Comment: It will contradict with your first condition that once clicked, same window and new tab will not show at the same time. Instead you can create another div for that. I'll edit my answer for other possible option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com",'myTab');
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")
```

[This is link to the Mozilla developer docs on Web API Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)